Generating Equation for randomisation of a long sequence for finding pairwise distance repeats
I am not mathematician. I am making a python code. I am generating a equation to do permutation. We want to analyze repeats in one sequence of pairwise distance and randomize it and calculate the probability which sequence repeat occur more number of times but it should be done in equation not with the permutation.
For example, I have a Sequence: ABCA
If we observed how many times one sequence distance appears in one sequence then in above sequence

Distance 1 AA appears zero time
Distance 2 AA appears zero time
Distance 3 AA appears 1 time
Same goes for others
Distance 1 AB appears 1 time
Distance 2 AB appears zero time
Distance 3 AB appears zero time
Same goes for AC Distance 1 AC appears zero time
Distance 2 AC appears 1 time
Distance 3 AC appears zero time
Same goes for BC, BA, CA If we randomise the sequence it would be like BACA, ABCA, CAAB, CABA, ACBA...... Now we have to calculate the distance in all the sequences like How many times each pair appears in all the sequences, like Distance 1 AA appears 1 time in x number of sequences Distance 2 AA appears 2 time in x sequences Distance 3 AA appears 2 time in x sequences

Then Calculate the probability at each distance. When I do this for large number of sequences combination number goes more than 10000000000000000000 that very computational intensive. I need an equation to calculate all the randomization and distance matrix with equation.

If I understand you correctly, you start with a fixed sequence $s$, and you permute it randomly to get a sequence $t$.  Then for each pair of letters $x,y$ you let $m_{x,y,d}$ be the number of $i,j$, $i<j$, such that $t_i = x$, $t_j = y$, and $j-i = d$. Then you want to know the probability that $m_{x,y,d} = n$ for any given $n$. Does that sound right?

Let's consider the sequence "WAWAA". First, we identify the unique residues in it: "A" and "W". Next, we create pairs of these residues (AW, WW, AA, WA) and find their locations within the sequence.

For instance, for the pair AA, the locations are 2, 4, and 5. We then calculate the pairwise distances: for AA, the distances are 5-2=3, 5-4=1, and 4-2=2, resulting in distances of 3, 1, and 2.

We compile a distribution of these distances, noting the frequency of each distance (e.g., for AA, the pairwise distance of 3 occurs once).

To generalize this for all possible permutations, we generate all permutations and repeat the above process for each permutation. Instead of summing the occurrences of each pairwise distance across permutations, we average them.

We then record the occurrences of each pairwise distance within each permuted sequence. Finally, we calculate the number of permuted or randomized sequences where each pairwise distance occurs exactly once, twice, thrice, and so on. The challenge lies in deriving an equation to determine the probability of a specific pairwise distance occurring a certain number of times within a sequence.

Although we have an equation to determine the average number of occurrences of a pairwise distance, determining the probability distribution for the occurrences remains unresolved.

@AmenShamim Can you answer JairTaylor 's question. The way you write it makes the question hard to understand

Yes, Fixed sequence is 's' and permute it randomly to get sequence 't'. Make matrix of each pair of letters , That is , but I m not sure what 'd' is in your case. My matrix is for distance and how many times one distance appears. If 'd' is showing distance and i, j number of times then yes. ti ≠ x, ti ≠ y and j-i ≠ d. Here matrix , has all the pairwise distances 'd' and how many times it appeared ith number.
